# What is map, function and transformation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

I confuse about the tranformation. There alot of tranformation types. I don't know that which one is general, which one is just a special case.

1. Map. What is the exactly map?

   - [From wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(mathematics)), there are also morphism and function. What exactly are they? Because when I read them, they seem to have same definition.
2. Function.

   - There are two definitions for "function" [this one (transformation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_(function)) and [this one (function)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)). So what exactly function?
3. Transformation. (main question)

   - Linear transformation, unitary transformation, orthogonal transformation, geometry transformation and coordinate transformation. Is there any transformation other than this? Which is the most general transformation? which on is a special case of some transformation? What is really definition of transformation?

Comment: As you can see from the Wiki's entry, they mean more or less the sam : a *map* is a *function*. In some contexts one term is preferred (mainly for "customary" reasons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it a bit easier try to think about functions as a Cartesian product between two sets. So

$$
f:A\to B 
$$

is a function or, mapping from a set $A$ to a set $B$, we can express this as

$$
f=\{(a,b)\mid a\in A, b\in B \} \subseteq A\times B
$$

so the elements of $f$ are ordered pairs of elements $(a,b)$.

A morphism is a strucure retaining mapping, which means that some structural property in set $A$ carries over to $B$ in some form. To say an example let $\phi$ be a function mapping elements of $A$ to elemnts of $B$ that is

$$
\phi\subseteq A\times B
$$

moreover

$$
\phi(a_1\circ a_2)=\phi(a_1)\circ\phi(a_2), \quad \forall a_1,a_2\in A
$$

so the operation "$\circ$" carries through. It doesn't matter wether you use it before or after applying $\phi$.

As for the last question, there are many different types of transformations. A transformation is also a function that is a cartesian product between two sets. That is the most general form of a transformation.

Hope this helped a bit